# One-liner Perl command to rename files

Tags: perl

So far this one-liner is stripping off one line and renaming the file, but I need help to alter it so that it strips that line I am looking for `Data for` and remove the old file extension `.csv` instead of adding to it. (`.csv.out`). I am not sure if this can be done with one-liner.

Instead it's adding on the the extension `filename.csv.out`

#### Example

```
 test_20110824.csv.out
```

One-liner:

```
find -type f -name '*.csv' -exec perl -i.out -wlne '/^Data for/ or print' {} \;
```

I want to replace the extension:

```
test_20110824.out
```

Comment: have a look at the perl [rename](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html) utility... `$ rename 's/\.csv$/\.out/' *.csv`

Comment: This is [the fancy version of rename](http://training.perl.com/scripts/rename).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -MFile::Copy -we 'for (glob "*.csv") { my ($name) = /^(.+).csv/i; move($_, $name . ".out"); }'
```

To remove the header matching `Data for`:

```
perl  -MFile::Copy -MTie::File -wE 'for (glob '*x.csv') { tie my @file,
"Tie::File", $_ or die $!; shift @file if $file[0] =~ /^Data for/; 
untie @file; my ($name) = /^(.*).csv/i; move($_, $name . ".out"); }'
```

But then it's really not a one-liner anymore...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use File::Copy;
use autodie;

for (@ARGV) {
    tie my @file, "Tie::File", $_;
    shift @file if $file[0] =~ /^Data for/;
    untie @file; 
    my ($name) = /^(.*).csv/i; 
    move($_, $name . ".out");
}
```

And use with:

```
$ script.pl *.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing an initial match for a header `Data for` which I want to strip out before renaming it. Can I add that to this string?

Comment: That's a whole other question.. well, let's see.

Comment: sorry, should have made that clear. as i'm performing that step in my original one-liner.

Comment: Edited answer. Not sure this can be done smoothly with a one-liner.

Comment: can you elaborate on the line `my ($name) = /^(.*).csv/i;` I know its doing a match. What is the `i` at the end doing? thanks again.

Comment: The `/i` is a modifier. You can read about it [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).

Answer (score 1):

A simple Bash shell script will suffice

```
(shopt -s failglob; for i in *.csv.out; do echo mv $i ${i%csv.out}out; done)
```

The `shopt -s failglob` is needed to ensure that if there are no matches the command will fail instead of trying to rename `*.csv.out` to `*.out`.  The construct `${i%csv.out}out` removes a trailing `csv.out` and replaces it with just `out`.

As I have coded it here, this will just echo the commands it would execute.  When you're satisfied it does what you want, remove the word `echo`.